# SSMTP cannot send purchase confirmation email

Tags: email

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1 on my Ubuntu localhost. I installed ssmtp to send email. I tried subscribe letter on my website and receive confirmation email, so it worked.

However, when I checkout a product. It didn't send any email to customer's email address.

I opened var/log/mail.log. All subscription confirmation mails are here, but there isn't any checkout mail.

I guess the problem is between Magento and SSMTP..

Please help. I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Magento 1.9.1 magento introduced an `email_queue` to send emails based on your cron configuration. If you have access to the database look in the `core_email_queue` table and you should see the email waiting to be sent there.

Comment: Yea, I have just found out it as well. Each time I run file cron.php, the emails will be sent, if not, nothing will be sent. What should I do?

Comment: Its up to you, if its a development environment and your specifically testing emails then you'll need to set-up a cron job or keep running cron.php. Personally when i'm developing i prefer not to set this up unless I'm specifically modifying/testing this functionality.